# if <xsl:value-of> returns null remove the element +XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

Hi I am working with a xslt in http://xsltransform.net/bFWR5Er/12
There are some nodes which does not return any value.
Is it possible to remove the nodes if  doesnot return any value.

For example I want to remove
      `<OrderNumber/>
      <MemberID/>
      <AccountNumber/>
      <AssociateID/>
      <Telephone/>
      <ReceiptNumber/>
      <SerialNumber/>
      <ItemCode/>
      <FirstName/>
      <LastName/>
      <EmailAddress/>
      <StoreNumber/>
      <TerminalNumber/>
      <ReceiptDate/>
      <GiftRegistryID/>`
All these node as it does not contain any value.
Only `<TransactionNumber>1843</TransactionNumber>` will be kept as output along with its parent nodes.

Comment: Please minimize your example and post it here.

Comment: Identity transform plus empty templates for all he elements you want to remove.

Comment: http://xsltransform.net/bFWR5Er/15

Comment: Thanks a lot Maria. You have made it exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the answer is given by Maria Deleva. I have just modified it a bit as per my requirement.

'http://xsltransform.net/bFWR5Er/18'